# Iterating through a 3rd degree nested dictionary in swift 4

Tags: swift, dictionary

I have dictionary created by a couple nested dictionaries, that looks like this:

`var apartments: [Block : [Floor : [Side : (Int, Int) ]]`

I want to iterate between al pf it’s components to get the sum of all the first integers in the tuple (S1), and the sum of all the second integers in the tuple (S2).

Here's the actual code:

```
enum Side {
    case right
    case left
}

enum Floor {
    case GF
    case FirstFloor
    case Duplex
}

enum Block {
    case A
    case B
    case C
    case D
}

var apartments: [Block : [Floor : [Side : (Int, Int) ]]] = [
    .A: [
        .GF: [
            .right: (33, 140),
            .left: (33, 140)
        ],
        .FirstFloor: [
            .right: (36, 150),
            .left: (36, 150)
        ],
        .Duplex: [
            .right: (50, 210),
            .left: (50, 210)
        ]
    ],

    .B: [
        .GF: [
            .right: (33, 140),
            .left: (33, 140)
        ],
        .FirstFloor: [
            .right: (36, 150),
            .left: (36, 150)
        ],
        .Duplex: [
            .right: (50, 210),
            .left: (50, 210)
        ]
    ],

    .C: [
        .GF: [
            .right: (33, 133),
            .left: (38, 148)
        ],
        .FirstFloor: [
            .right: (36, 141),
            .left: (39, 153)
        ],
        .Duplex: [
            .right: (50, 200),
            .left: (58, 225)
        ]
    ],

    .D: [
        .GF: [
            .right: (38, 140),
            .left: (38, 140)
        ],
        .FirstFloor: [
            .right: (39, 146),
            .left: (39, 146)
        ],
        .Duplex: [
            .right: (58, 214),
            .left: (58, 214)
        ]
    ]
]
```

Comment: I would recommend against using such deeply nested datastructures directly. I would recommend you make datatypes that stores list of sides, floors and blocks, and expose convenient operations on those.

Comment: @Alexander the problem is that the numbers are assigned in a non-logical manner. If u have any clear example, i would really appreciate it.

Comment: Well you'll need to describe to us, in much greater detail, exactly what you're trying to model here, and then perhaps I could suggest an improvement. As it stands, there's a very obvious red flag with this approach to modelling this data, and it's that un acquainted readers (such as myself) has *no* idea what's being modelled. What are the numbers? What's being summed? I have no idea.

Comment: @Alexander the first number is the number of voting shares in the compound, the second is the one for the block

Comment: "the second is the one for the block"?

Comment: @Alexander well, as an easier way of explanation, these are numbers related to the areas of each apartment in comparison to the area of the full block (building) and to all four blocks

Comment: That sounds like something you should express in your data model. Why not make data types for `Building`, `BuildingFloor`, `Apartment`, etc. `Building` can have an Array/Dict of `BuildingFloor`s, each of which will have an array/dict of `Apartment`s, and then, `Apartment` can have `area` and `voting shares` properties.

Comment: @Alexander that sounds good, ill try it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173434/discussion-between-alexander-and-fayyouz).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
func sum() -> Int {
    var x = 0
    for (block, floors) in apartments {
        for (floor, sides) in floors {
            for (side, FOO) in sides { // idk what the value here is. Rename FOO
                x += FOO
            }
        }
    }
    return x
}
```

Even better, you can just use `flatMap` and `reduce`:

```
func sum(_ apartments: [Block : [Floor : [Side : (Int, Int) ]]]) -> Int {
    return apartments
        .values
        .lazy
        .flatMap { $0.values }
        .flatMap { $0.values }
        .flatMap { $0.0 }
        .reduce(0, +)
}

print(sum(apartments)) // => 1000
```

Comment: The second answer seems clean. Can you please link me to an explaination of it, cz i've never heard of this.

Comment: @Fayyouz It seems so, because it is :D https://medium.com/@abhimuralidharan/higher-order-functions-in-swift-filter-map-reduce-flatmap-1837646a63e8

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:

```
func sum() -> Int {
var x = 0
for (block, _) in apartments {
    for (floor, _) in apartments[block]! {
        for (side, _) in apartments[block]![floor]! {
            x += apartments[block]![floor]![side]!.0
        }
    }
}
return x
}
```

Comment: When you iterate a dictionary, you get key value pairs. You're using the key (`block`, `floor`, `side`) but then disregarding the values (`_`), only to then use the key to look up the value and force unwrap. On the bright side, at least this force unwrap won't crash. But you can just use the value provided to you, directly.